# Custom auto completions in vim, like Sublime Text 2

Tags: vim, sublimetext2

Just found about the [autocomplete](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/completions.html) feature in Sublime Text 2.

Example auto complete file:

```
{
        "scope": "text.html - source - meta.tag, punctuation.definition.tag.begin",

        "completions":
        [
                { "trigger": "a", "contents": "<a href=\"$1\">$0</a>" },
                { "trigger": "abbr", "contents": "<abbr>$0</abbr>" },
                { "trigger": "acronym", "contents": "<acronym>$0</acronym>" }
        ]
}
```

I tried to search for a similar thing for Vim, but haven't been able to find anything.

Does anything like this exist for Vim? Preferably if it uses simple to generate format, like JSON, YAML, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for [SnipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540), a good tutorial from Jeffrey Way: [Vim Essential Plugin: SnipMate](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/vim-essential-plugin-snipmate/)

Other plugins that can do something like you want: [SparkUp](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/vim-essential-plugin-sparkup/) or [Zen Coding.vim](http://mattn.github.com/zencoding-vim/)

Comment: I know and use SnipMate every day. I want partial autocomplete, which shows a dropdown after I type a single character.

Comment: Try `<c-r><tab>`. See `:h list-snippets` for more information.

Comment: Thanks for `<C-r><Tab>`! Vim tip of the week for me.

Comment: @Dogbert: SnipMate does that (at least it does if you're using [the garbas fork](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate)). When you type part of a snippet and hit tab, you get a dropdown menu of any matching snippets. Select one and hit tab to expand.

Comment: @pydave, nice! If only there was a way to make it run automatically, like most IDE's do. And close when I type something which is not a part of a snippet, or by pressing escape. Any ideas about that?

Comment: That's what AutoComplPop does, but for tags. I don't use it, but you might be able to get AutoComplPop to work for snippets too (or you could file a feature request).

Answer (score 3):

A more recent alternative to SnipMate seems to seems [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715), I haven't tried it myself though.

There is also [vim's built in abbreviations](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_abbreviations) support, but I don't think they support anything more complex than expanding a short text to a longer text. Still quite useful though.

Comment: I've been to the UltiSnips mountain and it is, amazing. Recommended!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [neocomplcache](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2620) or [autocomplpop](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879)? They seem to do what you want.